# How Change Detection Strategy works in Angular

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection, angular-changedetection

If I'm having multilevel components how change detection strategy works for example:

app-root component

```
var data = {
 name:"ajai"
}

<app-root>
  <first-child [input]="data">
  </first-child>
</app-root>
```

First-Child-component.html

```
{{data}}
<second-child> </second-child>
```

Inside first-child component we will be calling second-child as child component.

First-child-component.ts

```
  @Input('data') data = {}
```

If I change the value of data in App-component it will re render the whole tree. so First Child component I'm using change Detection Strategy OnPush so if any change made from app component will not affect its children rendering dom. to update value I'm just using changeDetectorRef detectChanges so data get Changed
by doing this actually what is happening in this tree rendering and how perfomance get increasing

Comment: The `<second-child>` is inside `first-child` template, or is it injected with `ng-content`?

Comment: Inside  first-child bro

Comment: You should separate it into 2 template in this case to avoid misunderstanding.

Comment: Now can you understand